# Why :DOWN info is not sent to GenServer?

Tags: elixir

I am experimenting with `GenServer`, I just created a linked process, and tried to kill it, to see how `handle_info` is called with `:DOWN` param

```
defmodule CSVServer do
use GenServer

import Logger
import Ecto.Query

def start_link(_opts \\ []) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, %{}, name: __MODULE__)
end



def test!(params), do: GenServer.call(__MODULE__, %{test: params})

def handle_call(%{test: params}, _from, state) do
    Agent.start_link(fn -> 0 end , name: {:global, "samir_sabri"})
    {:reply, %{test: params, status: 0}, :state}
end
```

Then, I tried to test using `iex` :

```
CSVServer.test! 0
%{status: 0, test: 0}

process= :global.whereis_name("process_name")
#PID<0.623.0>

Process.exit(process, :kill)
true
```

However, at the GenServer,`handle_info({:DOWN` was not called:

```
def handle_info({:DOWN, _, :process, _pid, reason}, state) do

        Logger.info "KILLED PROCESS"
        Logger.info (Kernel.inspect(_pid))
        Logger.info (Kernel.inspect(state))
        Logger.info (Kernel.inspect(reason))
        IO.puts "KILLED PROCESS #{_pid}, #{reason}, #{state}"
    end
```

Should it be called right after I kill the linked process?

Comment: Try adding `Process.flag(:trap_exit, true)` to your GenServer's `init/1`. Without that the GenServer will be killed as well if a process linked to it is killed.

Comment: If you do not want to trap exits, you may want to look into `Process.monitor/1`. The [getting started](https://elixir-lang.org/getting-started/mix-otp/genserver.html#monitors-or-links) guide has a nice intro on the difference between monitors and links.

Comment: Thanks, it's my first Genserver I do, its used as a worker, so what is recommended? To trap exits or to monitor?